Getting rid of Eclipse Junit 4 runtime configuration extraneous VM arguments
I'm fighting with Eclipse version 2024-09 right now when running junit tests.  When I go to run our Junit 4 (yes old) tests, it complains with very opaque error message:
Reference to undefined variable argLine

After poking around for a while I find that under the Run Configurations for the Junit test in question, in the VM arguments window there is not only -ea but also a whole bunch of additional arguments include ${argLine}.  Ok, good.  But I have no idea where that is coming from.  When I delete that configuration and re-run, the extra arguments come back.
The full argument list follows.  You can see that there are some obvious debug flags in there that I might set if doing some profiling or remove debugging.  But again, where are they coming from?
-ea
${argLine} -javaagent:${com.github.jbellis:jamm:jar}
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Xms512m -Xmx1g -DMHUB_DEV=true 

I did some searches and found people talking about the Installed JREs -> Edit -> Default VM arguments but none of my JREs have any arguments.
I've done a grep -r of "argLine" and "agentlib" down in my workspace configurations and maven pom.xml file to see if it was in some sort of plugin configurations or something.  I see it show up in the test run configurations but nowhere else.  I don't see it in the environment nor in any maven pom plugin configurations that I can find.  I've tried restarting Eclipse.
Any other ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Please include your pom.xml. If arguments are configured via the surefire plugin, recent Eclipse versions (like 2024-09) will pick it up (and the behaviorof it coming back when deleting and recreating the run configuration matches that). As this is fairly new, bugs with weird configurations could be possible.

You might also want to consider checking the effective POM (one of the tabs when viewing the pom.xml in Eclipse), especially if you are using a <parent> or similar.

Where is the pom.xml and "If I do a grep -r of argLine down in my workspace configurations..." without telling what and where you exactly searched for?! Come on, you have more then 100k reputation... Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

I did a grep of "argline" @howlger.  I edited my question to provide more detail.  If I could reproduce this then I would be able to fix it.  I'm not even sure how to reproduce this.

Thanks @dan1st.  It was indeed from the surefire plugin in one of the super poms.  Nothing changed in months with these but for some reason this problem cropped up yesterday.  Can you move your comment to an answer so I can accept it?

@Gray If you did grep -r "argLine\|agentlib" in your "maven pom.xml file" (as you added later), why didn't you find <argLine>...</argLine>? You question says that you can reproduce it: "When I delete that configuration and re-run, the extra arguments come back." But it does not say how other can reproduce it. To make the question helpful for others, please add the POM. You might adapt the following POM if you like https://github.com/howlger/Eclipse-IDE-improvements-videos/blob/2024-09/sample_code/Eclipse%202024-09%20Improvements/pom.xml

I did not find it because it was in 2 parent poms.  Also, none of our super poms were changed recently so I wasn't looking for them there.  And frankly I did not expect m2e to copy configuration into the Runtime Configuration inside of Eclipse so I wasn't even looking at my poms.  A bad assumption.

Now that you know the reason, you might add an example POM file so that your question will be useful to others who have the same problem. Obviously you have updated Eclipse from 2024-06 to 2024-09 and thereby m2e from 2.6.1 to 2.6.2 (or from earlier versions), which means that Maven Surefire configurations are now considered. But your question incorrectly says something about a version "2024.9", making your question harder to find for people facing the same issue.

Eclipse 2024-09 includes m2e 2.6.2 which added a new feature where arguments from the Maven surefire plugin would be propagated to run configurations.
So if your pom.xml contains CLI arguments for tests in the surefire or failsafe plugin similar to the following, these arguments would be copied:
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>
                        your arguments here
                    </argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

If these arguments are defined in a parent POM (a <parent> element referencing another artifact in the pom.xml), these are propagated as well. To check for that, you can open the pom.xml in Eclipse and open the Effective POM tab:

This should show you the full effective pom.xml that also includes content from parent POMs.
If you remove the arguments the error at startup from the pom.xml and update the Maven project by right-clicking on the project and selecting Maven > Update Project, it should stop trying to use these arguments.
If this is a bug where Eclipse fails to interpolate some properties, please create an issue in m2e including a minimal pom.xml reproducing it.

Wow!  Great answer.  Thanks so much.  So my upgrade to 2024.09 was what triggered this issue.

If you just updated yesterday, you might have even skipped that update and jumped to 2024-12 instead since that was released yesterday.

No I updated last week.  Just didn't come to run any unit tests until yesterday.  I assume the problem exists in 2024-12 as well?

Yes, that feature is there in 2024-12 as well. If you can create a [mcve] resulting in an error when running the tests manually but not with the CLI, please create a bugreport in m2e (except there is one already - but you should still test it with the newest version before).
